# Latex how to make capital A without the middle bar?

Tags: pdftex

have often seen in texts on Lie groups a capital A but without the middle bar but how to make such in Latex ? [image]

Comment: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: BTW, if either answer helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept the one you thought was best by clicking on the checkmark symbol.

Answer (score 17):

That's an upper-case lambda, which can be obtained in math mode as `\Lambda`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\gamma \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the case of Lie algebras you may actually be looking at `\wedge` or `\bigwedge` for the alternating algebra.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\gamma \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \bigwedge^2 \mathfrak{g}$
\end{document}
```

I would submit that $$\gamma \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \bigwedge^2 \mathfrak{g}$$ is the "right" way in this case, but there are people out there who use the $\Lambda$.